# Supporting quotations and string substitutions together in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following lines in repl

```
scala> val accountID = "123"
accountID: String = 123

scala> s"{\"AccountID\":\$accountID\, \"ProcessMessage\":\"true\", \"Reason\":\"Integration Test Message\"}"

<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.

s"{\"AccountID\":\"$accountID\", \"ProcessMessage\":\"true\", \"Reason\":\"Integration Test Message\"}"
           ^
```

I assume it's some small silly quotations thing, but I still want to understand what I am doing wrong here. If I put the account ID directly it evaluates fine.

Comment: Before you search for an error in your long string, this here produces essentially the same error: `s"\""`. Apparently, `s` doesn't like `\"` for whatever reason. Just use pamu's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use triple quotes and remove `\`s

```
scala> s"""{"AccountID":"${accountID}", "ProcessMessage":"true", "Reason":"Integration Test Message"}"""
res6: String = {"AccountID":"123", "ProcessMessage":"true", "Reason":"Integration Test Message"}
```